# Recover Data from a corrupted LVM after lvreduce?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, data-retrieval, lvm

I'm using an Ubuntu 13.04 server.
I wanted to reduce a logical volume, in order to increase another one.
The logical volume I wanted to reduce had a size of 100G and 69G used.

I tried to reduce a logical volume by using:

```
lvreduce -L20G /dev/mapper/root-vg
```

Unfortunately, I probably did it wrong, because after a reboot, my system was not able to boot properly anymore.

I've got an (initramfs) prompt and I seed that the mounting of /dev/mapper/root-vg failed on /root

Is there any way to, at least, get the data back ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten to shrink the filesystem before shrinking the LV. Make sure that you *do not* attempt to mount or repair the filesystem right now, because that could lead to filesystem corruption. If the data is important, I highly recommend making a full-disk backup before attempting recovery.

If you have a backup of the VG metadata, you should recover using that instead of the following. By default, LVM creates and stores backups in `/etc/lvm/{archive,backup}/` whenever you modify a VG, but I suspect you do not have access to this data.

To recover access to the filesystem, you need to re-extend the LV to at least its original size, **and also** make sure that the new logical extents are assigned in the same order as they were originally. This second condition will be hard to get right if you have a complicated configuration with many PVs. However, if you have a simple configuration with few PVs, and have not reassigned or removed the original logical extents, then the following *might* work (in a live USB environment):

```
lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/root-vg
```

See if you can mount the filesystem read-only:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/root-vg/
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/root-vg /mnt/root-vg/
```

If the mount is successful, then you should do a cursory examination of the files inside. If they look correct, then run an integrity check on filesystem (e.g., `fsck` on ext*, or `btrfs scrub` on btrfs).